# SQLAlchemy JOIN and ambiguous column name

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have this tables

```
class Domain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "domains"
    domain_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    domain_name = Column(String(), unique=True)


class Subdomain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subdomains"
    subdomain_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    subdomain_name = Column(String(), unique=True)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domains.domain_id'))


class Title(Base):
    __tablename__ = "titles"
    title_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    domain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('domains.domain_id'))
    subdomain_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subdomains.subdomain_id'))
    title = Column(String())
    status = Column(Integer())
    response_len = Column(Integer())
    created_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```

When I try this:

```
query = session.query(Domain.domain_name, Subdomain.subdomain_name, Title.title, Title.status, Title.response_len, Title.created_on, Title.updated_on)
query = query.join(Title).join(Subdomain).join(Domain)
```

I got:

```
ambiguous column name: domains.domain_name [SQL: 'SELECT domains.domain_name AS domains_domain_name, subdomains.subdomain_name AS subdomains_subdomain_name, titles.title AS titles_title, titles.status AS titles_status, titles.response_len AS titles_response_len, titles.created_on AS titles_created_on, titles.updated_on AS titles_updated_on \nFROM domains JOIN titles ON domains.domain_id = titles.domain_id JOIN subdomains ON subdomains.subdomain_id = titles.subdomain_id JOIN domains ON domains.domain_id = subdomains.domain_id']
```

Originally i had name in domains and name in subdomains, I tried to use labels - it doesn't help. I renamed it to domain_name and subdomain_name and still no luck.

Comment: Why do you join `Domain`?

Comment: To get domain_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Domain` is already introduced as the leftmost table in the join: `FROM domains JOIN ...`, due to it being the first table you select from in your query's select list. The explicit unaliased join is unnecessary, and causes your error. Simply omit it:

```
query = session.query(Domain.domain_name, Subdomain.subdomain_name, Title.title, Title.status, Title.response_len, Title.created_on, Title.updated_on)
query = query.join(Title).join(Subdomain)
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! God bless you!